# c++ winrt BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync() results in Access is denied

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am trying to write a c++ winrt application to connect to a Bluetooth LE device similar to the Microsoft example of [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE/cppwinrt). In the example I can connect to the Bluetooth device. However, when I am trying to create a new c++ winrt application with the same code, I am receiving the exception: 80070005 Access is denied.

In both application, I placed a button in the MainPage.xaml and added the following code to the MainPage.cpp file:

```
fire_and_forget MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice2{ nullptr };

        try {
         
            bluetoothLeDevice2 = co_await Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync(L"BluetoothLE#BluetoothLEd4:3b:04:bc:61:d1-88:33:14:d9:5b:88");
    
            if (bluetoothLeDevice2 == nullptr)
            {
                LogOnConsole(L"No connection.");
            }
        }
        catch (hresult_error & ex)
        {
            if (ex.to_abi() == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE))
            {
                LogOnConsole(L"Bluetooth radio is not on.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

}
```

In the example of Microsoft it works but in my own application bluetoothLeDevice2 is nullptr.

I compared both application and noted that my application uses a newer winrt library, but I do not know how to fix my code.

Comment: This incoreect call. You must use device i returned by devicewatcher class.

Comment: Have you declared the [bluetooth capability](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/BluetoothLE/cppwinrt/Package.appxmanifest#L42) in Package.appxmanifest?  `<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />`

Comment: This is presumably a UWP application that, by default, runs in a sandboxed environment. Capabilities are granted through the .appxmanifest. Compare yours to the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/BluetoothLE/cppwinrt/Package.appxmanifest)'s.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changing the settings in the appxmanifest solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP runs in a sandbox, if you want to [use Bluetooth in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth), you need to declare the bluetooth capability in the Package.appxmanifest.

```
<Capabilities> <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" /> </Capabilities>
```